# When creating a custom Collection, the variable referring to it doesn't use the default Add method

Tags: vba, class, collections

I created a custom Collection MyCollection:

```
Public MyCollection As Collection

Private Sub Class_Initialize()

    Set MyCollection = New Collection 

End Sub
```

---

From a Userform sub I call this Collection as follows:

```
Private Sub Test_Click()

Dim varCollection As MyCollection

Set varCollection = New MyCollection
```

Now using the `varCollection.Add` method doesn't work.
Instead I can only use `varCollection.MyCollection.Add`
What am I missing?

Comment: You need to make a method that adds to `MyCollection` as you have it now you have defined an object that contains a collection so you need to directly access that collection to add to it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm not sure what you mean. Isn't `varCollection` an object of type `MyCollection`?

Comment: Yes, which has a property that happens to be a collection, in order to access that collection you need to refer to that property. If you don't want to do that you need to make a method to add directly to that collection property.

Comment: Doesn't it inherit the `.Add` method, given that `MyCollection` was defined as a Collection?

Comment: No, that would defeat the purpose of making a class if it immediately added all the properties and methods of any object you add to it, what if you had two separate collections in there, which would it add to?

Comment: What you have now is similar to having a collection that contains a collection, you still need to access that inner collection to add to it, otherwise you're dealing with the outer collection. Same thing but with a user defined object that only has methods and properties added by you.

Comment: `MyCollection` the class is not synonymous with `MyCollection` the variable inside the class.

Comment: Ok, I think I see what you mean: `Public MyCollection As Collection` is the declaration of a variable of type Collection. And this variable is inside the collection `MyCollection`.  Do I need this inner collection (the variable)?

Comment: Your class is not a collection, it is a user defined object that has one property, a collection. It is not a collection itself.

Comment: ok..I see.. So with an additional `myadd` sub in `MyCollection`, I actually add items to the inner (collection-)variable `MyCollection`.

Comment: yeah, it might be helpful to name the variable and the class something different, it is a little confusing when they share a name.

Comment: Yes...Now I understand..So, I start the `MyCollection` class with the declaration `Private MyCollection()` and change the name of the inner collection variable to avoid confusion.

Comment: What you have now is called a collection *wrapper*. The collection is hidden in a class (declared private, not public) and the class exposes methods to modify the collection (but not the collection itself). To create a custom collection, see this: http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2010/07/04/custom-collection-class/